# Use vi.mock() from library inside setup file

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest, vitest

I am creating custom javascript library with content and testing part split into two entries by Vite.

```
// library/vite.config.ts

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: {
        content: path.resolve(__dirname, `src/index.ts`),
        testing: path.resolve(__dirname, `src/testing.ts`),
      },
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        `vitest`,
      ],
    },
  },
})
```

I want to mock whole library import and replace it in tests.

```
// library/src/testing.ts

import { vi } from 'vitest'

vi.mock(`my-library/content`, async () => { ... })
```

Then, I would like to use it only with import inside `setup.ts` file

```
// application/tests/setup.ts

import 'my-library/testing'
```

Problem is, that `vi.mock()` is not working.

I tried to use `vi.mock()` to existing application part which is worked:

```
// library/src/testing.ts

import { vi } from 'vitest'

// NOT WORKING
vi.mock(`my-library/content`, async () => { ... })

// WORKING
vi.mock(`application/something`, async () => { ... })
```

I also tried to use `vi.mock()` directly inside application, which is also working:

```
// application/tests/setup.ts

import { vi } from 'vitest'

// WORKING
vi.mock(`my-library/content`, async () => { ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I am using [pnpm workpaces](https://pnpm.io/workspaces). This problem was related with installed dependencies. After I added peer dependency to itself inside package.json, it started to work:

```
my-library/package.json

{
  ...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "my-library": "workspace:*"
  },
  ...
}
```